# What tabs are for a Hohner Unsere Lieblinge 32 hole harmonica?

Tags: tablature, harmonica

I just got my first harmonica, a Hohner Unsere Lieblinge 32 hole.
What kind of beginner tabs can I use?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Unsere Lieblinge 32 is tuned in the same tuning as the tremolo tuning in the Weiner system:

[Hohner harmonica tuning chart](https://www.hohner.de/fileadmin/documents/instruments/harmonicas/hohner-harmonicas-tuning-chart.pdf)

So you want to search for "Tremolo Harmonica Tabs". Choose simple songs you already know the melody of and add that tune name to your search terms to get started.

The Hohner tuning has an F# listed in their notes for the key of C harmonica, which seems unusual to me but I'm more familiar with the diatonic, Richter tuned models. You should check the manual that comes with the harmonica and verify the tuning.

Most of the tabs you will find online will be for the diatonic tuning, so it may be worth your time to learn the songs with notation or using actual note names instead of the tabs.

[Tremolo Harmonicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremolo_harmonica)

[Richter Tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter-tuned_harmonica)

Comment: Thank you so much that’s very useful and interesting. I would prefer learning by note names rather than the hole position type tabs. I play piano and uke so used to reading music and chords. However To do this I firstly need to identify the location of each note on the reeds. I wonder If you’re aware of where I could find a note location chart for my 32 hole harp. ? Thank you again 

Comment: The tuning chart in the answer has the note positions. look on the second page under Tremolo/Octave harmonicas

Comment: Ah ok I am right in thinking the note holes top and bottom are tuned an octave apart ? so the note changes depending on whether you blow or draw over the same pair of holes. I can see now why ppl may start with a simple 10 hole harp 

Comment: @AlphonsoBalvenie there's definitely a printing error on that diagram.  The 8 row harmonica (the "32) should be the same at the first 8 rows of the 10 row (the "40") harmonica below it.  Seems like there is a printing error in the bottom row, and it has some of the notes of a G harmonica by mistake.  So Tez should just ignore that one and read the below diagram of the 40 instead.

Comment: @tez 10 holes is actually the more complicated instrument.  Each hole has 2 reeds, played in each direction.  A tremolo harmonica has 1 reed per hole, and the rows are tuned the same.  So 1 hole on a diatonic is the same as 4 holes on a tremolo; a 10 hole diatonic tuning diagram looks the same as a 40 hole tremolo, because on a tremolo you have 2 holes for each note, but on a diatonic, you have 2 notes for each hole.  Actually, much more, because on a diatonic you also do bending to get "extra" notes, which doesn't exist on a tremolo.  Don't worry, you have started with the easier instrument.

Comment: @Tez So don’t worry about the two rows of holes, the point is to play the top and bottom row at the same time, so you play it like an "8 hole harmonica"). That’s why they’re tuned to the same note (on a tremolo) or in octaves (like yours). It's just like an accordion/organ stop, giving each note a "bigger" sound.  Don't think about it like "32 holes" but "8 squares", where each square is 4 little holes with 1 note blowing out, and another note breathing in.